# Upsert only changed/new fields?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following structure for a user which is stored in azure cosmos db:

{
id:string,
commentHistory:[]
}

When requesting a user I do an upsert passing the user id in, this is what I have:

```
string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            var toUpsert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(requestBody);

            var cosmos = Config.Cosmos.Get;
            var media = await cosmos.GetCollection("users");

            ResourceResponse<Document> result = await cosmos.UpsertDocument(Config.Cosmos.Keys.Collections.MediaCollection, toUpsert);
            return result.Resource;
```

What this seems to do is remove commentHistory as well.

Is it possible to do an upsert and only do the insert on the id if the document doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5):

Cosmos DB does not allow partial updates, so in your case, you'd need to:

1. Read the current document.
2. If there is none, create a new object.
3. Add the new history item.
4. Call Upsert.

There seems to be a design issue though. Your `commentHistory` attribute seems to be unbounded (could grow endlessly) which would make subsequent operations more expensive, in terms of RUs (since the document keeps growing larger and larger) and it could, at some point, hit the current document size limit (2Mb).

Another alternative is to keep a single document per comment history event with an added attribute as the `userId`.

In that case, in case of a new comment history event, you would always just do a `CreateDocumentAsync` and wouldn't have any unbounded issues.
If you wanted to obtain all the comment history of a particular user, you could query for comment history documents for a particular `userId`.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `Upsert` is to create a new document if not already existing, or to overwrite an existing one, there is no partial update.

If your intended workflow is to just create a user if not existing (and not updating it otherwise), I would suggest to try creating it and handle the conflict status code in `DocumentClientException` in case it already exists.

Is the code you posted called more frequently with new users or with existing ones? Based on how many user id conflicts you could have to face, you might also decide to follow a pessimistic approach and try to read the document (given the id) and insert it only if not existing.